# 401-Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: 2013

I am getting "**401-Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials**" when i  access the Tridion GUI.

However, if i have my user name added inside the "**Windows OS Administrators (Computer Management -->Local Users and Groups-->Groups-->Administrators**" group **in CMS installed machine**, I can able to login into Tridion GUI without any issue.

Evnironment Details: Windows Server 2012, Tridion 2013 SP1.

Anyone faced this issues? any suggestion will be great thankful.

Thanks,
jey

Comment: Are you added as a user in the CM itself?  Your CM application pool should be using the NetworkService account, while CM users should be valid Windows Domain accounts (or machine accounts).

Comment: Are you using LDAP or Active Directory to log into the TCM? The issue may be a few configuration settings on the Server 2012 box that need to be checked and verified the are set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshooting: Authentication Settings in IIS for SDL Tridion / SDL Tridion 2013 Web Application

- Access IIS -> Sites -> SDL Tridion 2013 under Features view find Authentication and ensure Windows Authentication alone is enabled
- Access IIS -> Sites -> SDL Tridion 2013 -> webdav under Features view find Authentication and ensure Basic Authentication and Windows Authentication is enabled
- Access IIS -> Sites -> SDL Tridion 2013 -> webservice under Features view find Authentication and ensure Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

On the Authentication page, select Anonymous Authentication. In the Actions pane, click Edit to confirm the security principal used for anonymous access.

Could you also check & confirm the permissions of the SDL Tridion **web application root path** & ensure following permissions exists on the folder:

**NETWORK SERVICE (Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write)**

IIS_IUSRS (Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write)

[image]

**1. Identify accounts that could not be resolved to a SID:**

From the command prompt, type: FIND /I "Cannot find"  %SYSTEMROOT%\Security\Logs\winlogon.log

The string following "Cannot find" in the FIND output identifies the problem account names.

Example: Cannot find JohnDough.

In this case, the SID for username "JohnDough" could not be determined. This most likely occurs because the account was deleted, renamed, or is spelled differently (e.g. "JohnDoe").

**2. Use RSoP to identify the specific User Rights, Restricted Groups, and Source GPOs that contain the problem accounts:**

a. Start -> Run -> RSoP.msc
b. Review the results for Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment and Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Restricted Groups for any errors flagged with a red X.
c. For any User Right or Restricted Group marked with a red X, the corresponding GPO that contains the problem policy setting is listed under the column entitled "Source GPO". Note the specific User Rights, Restricted Groups and containing Source GPOs that are generating errors.

**3. Remove unresolved accounts from Group Policy**

a. Start -> Run -> MMC.EXE
b. From the File menu select "Add/Remove Snap-in..."
c. From the "Add/Remove Snap-in" dialog box select "Add..."
d. In the "Add Standalone Snap-in" dialog box select "Group Policy" and click "Add"
e. In the "Select Group Policy Object" dialog box click the "Browse" button.
f. On the "Browse for a Group Policy Object" dialog box choose the "All" tab
g. For each source GPO identified in step 2, correct the specific User Rights or Restricted Groups that were flagged with a red X in step 2. These User Rights or Restricted Groups can be corrected by removing or correcting any references to the problem accounts that were identified in step 1

Answer (score 1):

The fact that adding yourself to the Administrators helps is interesting. It indicates that it's it's not about establishing your identity (authentication) but about authorisation (what that identity is allowed to do). (This interpretation places me in direct opposition to Rick's point of view... rarely a wise stance to take, but seeing as he is also speculating, I'll risk it. :-)

I'd be looking at how IIS is set up. Did you do everything with the Tridion installer, or are there some manual customisations? So, for example, what authentication method is configured for the GUI web site? (Maybe I *am* siding with Rick!) What application pool does it run under, and does the relevant app-pool account have the right permissions to run the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're providing the right credentials? The error message is rather explicit in stating that the credentials are wrong (so an authentication issue rather than an authorization issue, despite the HTTP error suggesting the latter). Are you using domain accounts (which are known on the server)?